# Check if a user is logged in to Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to check whether a user is logged in to Facebook (just logged in or not, with no relation to my application) using javascript.
I tried using the following code after FB.init:
`FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

    alert(response.status);

});`
edge.create is working just fine though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some hacks that can help, but not in your situation. https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information

Here is simple example:

```
<html> 
<head> 

</head>

<body>
// At the end of page will be good 
<script>
function logged() {
    alert('logged');
}
function notlogged() {
    alert('not logged');
}
</script>
<script src="http://www.facebook.com/ajax/composer/attachment/question/question.php" onload="logged()" onerror="notlogged()">
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (FB.getSession() != null) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response){
        alert ("Welcome " + response.name);
    })
}
```

With one caveat, though: the user needs to authorize your app in order to detect whether is logged in or not. I believe there is no way to detect it without it with this api: You can add a like button and such, but not interact with the fb status.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
                // alert('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                   alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                   });
               }
});
```